# Display unconfirmed transactions graph

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Where can one see a real time graph of current number of unconfirmed transactions (Y axis) over time (X axis)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Johoe's bitcoin mempool statistics](https://jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#0,24h) should work for you. It currently shows pending tx count, pending tx fees (btc), and pending mempool size (MB).